# Update Curl on Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: curl

I am updating curl from 7.35.0 to 7.60.0 on an ubuntu 14.04.3 server.  Followed the steps here https://gist.github.com/fideloper/f72997d2e2c9fbe66459

```
sudo apt-get build-dep curl
mkdir ~/curl
cd ~/curl
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.60.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf curl-7.60.0.tar.bz2
cd curl-7.60.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Looks like curl was updated.  But `curl -V` still shows

```
curl: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by curl)
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.60.0
```

`which curl` shows

```
/usr/local/bin/curl
```

`whereis curl` shows

```
curl: /usr/bin/curl /usr/local/bin/curl /usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz
```

/usr/bin/curl is the older version and /usr/local/bin/curl should be the new version.  How do I get the new version of curl used?  Can I safely remove /usr/bin/curl?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you run `/usr/local/bin/curl -V` directly?  With the full file path to it instead of just 'curl'

Comment: @ThomasWard that does output the correct updated curl version.

Comment: Have you closed your terminal and reopened it yet, then run just `curl`?  Just to rule out some odd PATH problem.

Comment: @ThomasWard got the updated curl version by reopening the terminal.  I had restarted Apache and thought that would have been enough.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad that fixed the problem.  I converted that to an answer for you so you can mark the question as answered/solved by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install a new software that would have a version which supersedes the version in `/usr/bin/` or anywhere else in the `$PATH`, you need to usually restart your terminal session.

Close out your terminal session or your SSH connection.  Once you start it back up, you should then be able to use the 'newer' version (`/usr/local/bin/...` will supersede `/usr/bin/...` when the same application is in both locations but with different versions, typically.)